# Setting multiple values in session storage in angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I am trying to send a object and an int to the storage on a click event. They need to be mapped together.
I don't know the syntax for this.

HTML with onClick changes-

```html
<button  class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100 my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="onAddCart(movie, movie.aPrice)">Rent</button>
<button  class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100 my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="onAddCart(movie, movie.aPurchasePrice)">Purchase</button>
```

In the service, I want to map that price to the object I am sending.
How do i update the functions according to this.

Service.ts file-

```js
addMovieToCart(movies: any,price : number) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('movie', JSON.stringify(movies));
  }
  getMovieFromCart() {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('movie'));
  }
  removeAllMovieFromCart() {
    return sessionStorage.removeItem('movie');
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(sessionStorage.movie)?

Comment: What do you mean with "map that price to the object"? Something like `{price: price, movie: movie}` or in short `{price, movie}`?

Comment: what I meant was that how can I send the specific movie object and the price in such a way, that when I try to get the a particular movie object, I can also get the price I sent with the movie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator.

```
 export class AppComponent  {

  public obj: {} = {"name": "peter"};

  constructor() {
    console.log (this.obj);
    console.log ({...this.obj, "age": 22});
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-spread-operator?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to store both the movie and its price in the same object:

```
const record = { movie, price }; 
sessionStorage.setItem('movie', record);
```

However this way you can't easily store multiple movies or retrieve them by id.

A better approach would be to store all movies in a shared object.

```
const record = { movie, price };
// Default to empty dictionary if there is no movies record yet.
const existingMoviesJSON = sessionStorage.getItem('movies') || '{}';
const movies = JSON.parse(existingMoviesJSON);
// Assuming your movie has an id, but you could also use a unique name.
movies[movie.id] = record;
sessionStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(movies));
```

This way you can then retrieve movies with their price by id:

```
getMovieFromCart(movieId) {
    const movies = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('movies') || '{}');
    // Will return undefined if the movieId can't be found in the dictionary so be sure to handle this error.
    return movies[movieId];
}
```